# Prove that polynomial $p$ is not the zero polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let $A=\pmatrix{1 & \alpha & \alpha^2\\ 1 & \beta & \beta^2\\ 1 & \gamma & \gamma^2}$
Furthermore we have the function $p$:

$p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$,

$x \mapsto \det\pmatrix{1 & \alpha & \alpha^2\\ 1 & \beta & \beta^2\\ 1 & x & x^2}$, $\alpha\neq \beta$.

My objective is to prove that $p$ is a polynomial that is different from the zero polynomial and to determine its roots.

I get that:
$\det(A) = \; (\alpha - \beta) \; (\alpha - \gamma) \; (\gamma - \beta)$.

I can conclude that $A$ is invertible if and only if $\alpha$,$\beta$ and $\gamma$ are all distinct.

I also observe that if $A$ is row-equivalent to $I_3$, then it's invertible.

Before row reducing $A$, don't I have to assume that $\det(A) \neq 0$ (and therefore basically assuming that $\alpha ,\beta$ and $\gamma$ are pairwise different from each other, which is what I want to prove)?

How do I proceed?

Comment: What is the purpose of the function $p$?  $\det(A)$ does not depend on $x$.

Comment: You can do row reduction of any matrix; you just need to be careful when dividing, to make sure you are not dividing by zero.

Comment: "How do I proceed?" You don't tell us what it is you are trying to establish!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The question is in the title.

Comment: @kccu: **A** question in the title; but there is no polynomial in the body of the question.

Comment: This is not true. Let $\gamma=\beta$ or $\gamma=\alpha$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin There is, it's just a constant polynomial as written. Perhaps the argument of the polynomial is meant to be one of $\alpha, \beta,\gamma$.

Comment: @MartinR You are completely correct. I made a mistake when I wrote down the problem on my paper, which gave me this mistake. Edited. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to assume anything (in principle) to do row reduction. You have 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & \alpha & \alpha^2\\ 1 & \beta & \beta^2\\ 1 & \gamma & \gamma^2\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}1 & \alpha & \alpha^2\\ 0 & \beta -\alpha& \beta^2-\alpha^2\\ 0 & \gamma-\alpha & \gamma^2-\alpha^2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If $\beta-\alpha=0$, the second row is zero. If $\gamma-\alpha=0$, the third row is zero. In either case, $A$ is not invertible. When $(\beta-\alpha)(\gamma-\alpha)\ne0$, you can continue the row reduction
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & \alpha & \alpha^2\\ 0 & \beta -\alpha& \beta^2-\alpha^2\\ 0 & \gamma-\alpha & \gamma^2-\alpha^2\end{bmatrix}\to
\begin{bmatrix}1 & \alpha & \alpha^2\\ 0 & 1& \beta+\alpha\\ 0 & 1 & \gamma+\alpha\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}1 & \alpha & \alpha^2\\ 0 & 1& \beta+\alpha\\ 0 & 0 & \gamma-\beta\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now if $\gamma-\beta=0$ you are done and $A$ is not invertible; if $\gamma-\beta\ne0$, you can continue
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & \alpha & \alpha^2\\ 0 & 1& \beta+\alpha\\ 0 & 1 & \gamma-\beta\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}1 & \alpha & \alpha^2\\ 0 & 1& \beta+\alpha\\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\to
I_3.
$$